# Spring default validator vs Hibernate validator : Which is better?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

My project have to migrate from `Spring MVC` to `Spring boot`,and we are managed to initialize Spring boot from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) and it is bundled with `spring validation` by default. There is a confusion among us to choose either `Spring default validator` or `Hibernate validator`.
Please advice!!

Comment: Hibernate validator is a reference implementation of Bean Validation spec, Spring Validation (`Validator` interface) is it's own thing. Usually both are used because Hibernate constraint validation can be easily integrated into Spring. In fact, Spring Boot should do it automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a day's research I have found out a few facts.

As of now **Spring Boot 1.5.9** by default comes with  `Bean Validation 1.0` (JSR-303) and `Bean Validation 1.1` (JSR-349)

- Java Bean Validation (JSR 303) is a framework that has been approved by the JCP as of Nov 2009 and is accepted as part of the Java EE 6 specification.
- Bean Validation 1.1 (JSR 349) was finished in 2013.It is part of Java EE 7.

**Hibernate  Validator 6.X** on the other hand is the reference implementation `Bean Validation 2.0` (JSR 380).

- Support for the JSR 310 date/time types for @Pastand@Future
- New built-in constraints:`@Positive`, `@PositiveOrZero`, `@Negative`, `@NegativeOrZero`, `@PastOrPresent` and `@FutureOrPresent`
- Bean Validation 2.0 will also be part of the Java EE 8 platform.

Here is the comparison of built-in constraints of theese two(**Click on `Run code snippet` and see annotation wise comparison.**)

```css
.w3-table,.w3-table-all{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100%;display:table}.w3-table-all{border:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-bordered tr,.w3-table-all tr{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.w3-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#fff}.w3-table-all tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f1f1f1}
.w3-hoverable tbody tr:hover,.w3-ul.w3-hoverable li:hover{background-color:#ccc}.w3-centered tr th,.w3-centered tr td{text-align:center}
.w3-table td,.w3-table th,.w3-table-all td,.w3-table-all th{padding:8px 8px;display:table-cell;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.w3-table th:first-child,.w3-table td:first-child,.w3-table-all th:first-child,.w3-table-all td:first-child{padding-left:16px}
.red{
color : red;
}
.green{
color : green;
}
```

```html
<table class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Annotations / Features</th>
      <th>Hibernate Validator 6.X</th>
      <th>Spring default Validator</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>@AssertFalse</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@AssertTrue</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@DecimalMax</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@DecimalMin</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Digits</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Future</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Max</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Min</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@NotNull</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Null</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Past</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Pattern</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Size</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Negative</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@NegativeOrZero</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Positive</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@PositiveOrZero</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@PastOrPresent</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@FutureOrPresent</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@NotEmpty</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@NotBlank</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@Email</td>
      <td class="green">Yes</td>
      <td class="red">No</td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
</table>
```